# My custom django login view won't work

Tags: python, django

I was trying to make my own custom login page to test my django skills but it would never work. My View:

```
def login_view(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            redirect('/account/')
        else:
            print(str(password)+" "+str(email))
else:
    form = LoginForm()
return render(request, 'users/login.html',{'form': form})
```

My Forms

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
email = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'registerforms', 'placeholder': 'Email'}),
    label='',
)
password = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'registerforms', 'placeholder': 'Password'}),
    label='',
)
```

My urls

```
url(r'^login/$', views.login_view, name='login_view'),
```

My Template

```
<form action="" method="post" role="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you post the stack trace if there is any?
Are you sure about the form is valid every time you try to login?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:
user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
the default authenticate backend use username (and not email) to authenticate the user. If if you want to use email you need to create a custom backend. You can create one by following the instructions here (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#authentication-backends)

Also, you need put "return" in front of the redirect('/account/') for the redirection to work properly (otherwise it returns the form again by executing the return render(...) at the end of the function).